# Getting value of a row in psql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am running this command:

```
INSERT INTO groupmembers (memberid, groupid)

VALUES(60, SELECT get_groupid());
```

and I get this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

Running

```
SELECT get_groupid();
```

gives the following:

```
get_groupid
-----------
         61
(1 row)
```

I am trying to get get the value 61 but instead getting the row with that. How do I get the value inside that row instead?

This is what get_groupid looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_groupdid() RETURNS int
AS $$ 
DECLARE 
groupid int;
BEGIN
SELECT groups.id INTO STRICT groupid
FROM groups WHERE name = 'Tier 1';
RETURN groupid;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Do you really need a function without parameters to return the same value? That looks like a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
VALUES(60, get_groupid())
```